# I can't write a python average function that will average 3 input integers from user. (average has to be in float)

Tags: python, input, user-defined-functions, average

Can't write a functional python code that asks users to enter three integers, pass through a function named (avg) and will return the average as a (float) value.

Comment: Why not? If you want to ask a question, ask a question.

Comment: Can you please add some of the code that you've tried and ask for help in the errors?

Answer (score 2):

The formula for average is the sum of the arguments divided by the amount of arguments. So you add the 3 arguments and then divide by 3 for what you want!

```
   def average(a,b,c):
        mean = (a + b + c)/3.0
        return mean
```

**note:** I use 3.0 instead of 3 so the result is a float!

now on top of all of this, you might want a function that will deal with a bunch of different inputs! so `*args` is the way you want to do this so you can write a function that will take an arbitrary number of arguments to average:

```
In [45]: def average(*args):
   ....:     return sum(args)/float(len(args))
   ....: 

In [46]: average(1,10,4,5,8,9)
Out[46]: 6.166666666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python2, you need to make sure to force the divison to float

```
>>> (3+3+4)/3
3
>>> (3+3+4)/3.0
3.3333333333333335
```